# I need help understanding 「虫が止まったみたいな扱いだ。」

Tags: definitions

I need help understanding this sentence,

> 虫が止まったみたいな扱いだ。

The Context is that the speaker is frustrated with what his conversation partner is doing/saying, but he is trying to help him as they have a client-employer relationship.

I tried looking it up in Japanese, but nothing would come up. I'd really appreciate if someone could tell me what this  means. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This 虫が止まった means an insect sticks to someone. How do most people feel when an insect sticks to them? Probably, they feel a bit bad or nothing, and then they brush it off. The speaker complains that he is treated like that.

Comment: It may not be obvious to learners, but one of the meanings of とまる is for a flying thing to land somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

虫が止まったみたいな扱いだ
Let me explain grammar and meaning for you

扱い means treatment  and みたいな (using for modify noun 扱い)means “like”. And 虫が止まった means insect stay,stop, stick in someone. So, the meaning is “ you act like a insect sticks into someone”.     (When insects stay or stick in your body, you feel frustrate right?)